# How to decide on Information storage in React

Tags: reactjs

I have tried to search for a question related to this concern but I can't seem to find anything. Perhaps it might have been phrased differently, but here's my concern:

I am creating a Real Estate listing application and I am planning on using React with ASP.NET Core Web API.

### The Problem:

When it comes to react, I understand State management and how data flows from component to component but I can't seem to know what kind of information actually need to be on state storage(e.g Redux store) and which should be loaded(from web api) every time a resource is requested.

For example:

> I can save user related information in a Redux store because only that user
> modifies that information. What happens in a Multi-User environment
> where when I store that information in a Redux store, then someone else
> updates database on their side... I am still left with the old
> information still backed in my Redux store. I would understand that
> creating a listener(via `setInterval`) that runs every few minutes to look for changes
> would be ideal but I am not sure if that would be the right path/approach for
> me.

So with the example above, I can't seem to know when to put information in a state. In my application, different agents will be working under 1 company and it's possible that they can all change some data at the same time. While this is very easy to handle back-end, I can't seem to get to know if such information needs to be stored in a state store(using Redux for example)... Think about Facebook home page. You get updates on your friend's posts, but are these posts actually stored in your state store? or they are actually requested everytime you click home link?

### The Question:

Given the scenario above, can you, based on your understanding and experience, outline in simple bulletin when to decide when information is worth storing in a state store(Redux Store). And when I should actually request information on every resource request(i.e. only fetch information from api when a link is requested).

Thank you very much for your Time in in answering this question.

Answer (score 1):

Let me start by simplifying when you should use state vs. any other option (eg. a regular JS variable).  You want to use something else whenever possible ... *except* when the value affects what your component renders (ie. what JSX it returns in its function or render method).  If you just follow that simple rule it will always answer when you should/shouldn't use state.

Understanding that, the rest of your question really has nothing to do with state: if the changes on your server affect what your component returns, you should keep them in state, and otherwise regular variables will suffice.

As for which technique you use to get information that's really a separate question (one you can probably find an answer to just by searching).  In short you can make an AJAX request (eg. use `fetch`) periodically (eg. using `setInterval`), or there are more advanced methods of "polling", or in other words periodically checking the server for information.

P.S. I should mention that if your problem is updating a piece of your data (out of a much larger mess of data), tools like Redux or the Apollo GraphQL framework (which builds in client-side data caching, and automatic updating of that cache when you make GraphQL queries ... but adopting GraphQL for your API, or even just Redux, is a major project).

Comment: I was basically referring to my state store in which case Redux is another example of storing state information. Based on your explanation, can we take Facebook Posts as an example. My home page on Facebook, Are my friend's posts stored in my client side store? I mean whatever facebook uses similar to Redux(I don't know what they use). If that is the case, What happens when my friend's post is modified? does facebook store all that posts data and request updates on everything based on that `setInterval` ?  Or infact they run api requests everytime home page is requested? Can you elaborate?

Comment: First, Facebook, doesn't (that I know) use Redux, but they did hire its creator: he's now on the React team.  Second *everything* ... all of the data your client needs ... needs to be kept in some sort of client-side conceptual state.  Whether it should be *React state* again comes down to the rule I said.  If you want to show updates, you have to make your client repeatedly get new data, and when it gets that new data you have to update your state variables, making them re-render.

Comment: P.S. This isn't *exactly* what you're looking for, but I think you might find it helpful.  It's basically Facebook describing a philosophy of one-direction state changes (Flux) that guides React ... and it came out of them making the Facebook Messenger web app, and dealing with various remote updates in it: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nYkdrAPrdcw  But honestly higher level "how should I do my app" questions like this are just not well suited to Stack Overflow; somewhere like Reddit might be better.

Comment: +1 for your time @machineghost Really appreciate it. I think my question was indeed related to when to use state manager like Redux. But somehow it wasn't clear to that point... But your first paragraph really reminded me of the real truth behind the use of state.

Comment: Glad I could help.  And P.S. Don't introduce complexity unless you need it, just as a general rule.  Definitely learn about great technologies like Redux, but only use them if React's built in stuff (state/context) isn't enough for you.

Comment: Yes, I was so far in the app, but with my limited knowledge on Redux, I was starting to panic because I'm pushing to launch. So at some point I had to re-do everything back into Asp.Net Razor Pages because it was Pandemonium as soon as I thought about Redux... But I somehow have a feeling that I won't be giving my customers that user experience I was looking for, which react to provide. Hence, I just thought of posting this question.